# How to override the memory limits in GeoServer cross layer filtering?

Tags: geoserver, cql-filter, jvm, crossfilter

According to this [document](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/querylayer/index.html) retrieving of minimum features and coordinates can be override by using `QUERY_LAYER_MAX_FEATURES` and 
`GEOMETRY_COLLECT_MAX_COORDINATES`. This can be done using JVM system variables, servlet context variables, or environment variables.

My doubt is where to set these values. Can any one explain briefly?
What is meant by JVM system variables?

Comment: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/datadirectory/setting.html

Answer (score 1):

The JVM is the virtual machine that runs your Java code, in the case of GeoServer it is the JVM that is running the container that GeoServer is in, usually tomcat or jetty but possibly something more exotic. How you set a JVM variable varies depending on which container you are running and how you are running it (and which OS you use).

1. If you are using tomcat then see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738794/add-jvm-options-in-tomcat)
2. If you are using Jetty then see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647795/passing-java-options-to-jetty-sh)

In both cases you need to add a string like

```
-DQUERY_LAYER_MAX_FEATURES=1000 -DGEOMETRY_COLLECT_MAX_COORDINATES=40
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm using tomcat then how to set above two parameters (GEOMETRY_COLLECT_MAX_COORDINATES and QUERY_LAYER_MAX_FEATURES )

Comment: In which file we have to add?  Is it in web.xml?

Answer (score 0):

For running on a Windows machine (I have Apache Tomcat 8.0 running on Windows server 2012)

1. Logon to the server
2. hit Start
3. start typing Enviroment
4. select "Edit the system environment variables"
5. click button Environment Variables
6. add new System variable -> name: QUERY_LAYER_MAX_FEATURES value: 10000